# how to get Percentage coverage of each ApexClass through SOQL

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

Is there any way we can query Like below and get the result

`Query:    SELECT Percentagecovered,ApexClassname FROM ApexCodeCoverage` or
 How can i convert below query to get % covered.

```
SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ASC
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking about this Tooling API query? You have the lines covered and uncovered in your query already; you can calculate the percentage covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To query for code coverage, specify an Apex class, test class, or
>   both. The returned JSON or XML object will contain two lists of
>   integers: one for covered and one for uncovered lines.

```
 SELECT Coverage FROM ApexCodeCoverage WHERE ApexClassOrTrigger = ‘01pD000000066GR’ AND ApexTestClass = ‘01pD000000064pu’
```

Coverage includes the following fields:

- coveredLines
- namespace
- uncoveredLines

Code coverage percentage is a simple calculation of the number of covered lines divided by the sum of the number of covered lines and the number of uncovered lines. For example, **to calculate code coverage percentage in SOAP:**

```
ApexCodeCoverage acc = null; //Query for an ApexCodeCoverage object 
Coverage coverage = acc.coverage; 
int[] covered = coverage.coveredLines; 
int[] uncovered = coverage.uncoveredLines; 
int percent = covered.length / (covered.length + uncovered.length); 
System.out.println("Total class coverage is " + percent + "%.");
```

Reference:-
[ApexCodeCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm)

Better to go for other tool where you can easily get whole analysis:-

1. https://www.aside.io/ //just login with your org and run all test get the whole analysis
2. Salesforce advanced Code searcher:-
   By using the advanced quick find you can get your code few clicks shorter. Also, you can search any string your code

Comment: @DavidMycka Welcome :)