# Run Test Suite from Apex

Tags: code-coverage, execute-anonymous, test-suite

I have a test suite which contains all test classes.

I want to run the test suite from Anonymous Window so at the end of suite run completion I can create custom object records to track the coverage. Using this(Referred from [how to get Percentage coverage of each ApexClass through SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229515/how-to-get-percentage-coverage-of-each-apexclass-through-soql)):

```
ApexCodeCoverage acc = null; //Query for an ApexCodeCoverage object 
Coverage coverage = acc.coverage; 
int[] covered = coverage.coveredLines; 
int[] uncovered = coverage.uncoveredLines; 
int percent = covered.length / (covered.length + uncovered.length); 
System.out.println("Total class coverage is " + percent + "%.");
```

With this approach I don't need to watch the screen all time and will not loose the coverage details.

I can run the apex at night and can check the coverage in morning.

Does anyone have idea how can I run the test suite from the apex?

Answer (score 0):

Apex cannot do this for you.

Sure, you could make a callout to start a run of your test suite through the Tooling API, but the issue you'd run into there is the limit on how much time you can spend waiting on a callout. If that weren't an issue, you'd still have a problem with the overall time limit for an Apex transaction.

Instead, this is something you should look at scripting using the Salesforce CLI (which does provide `sfdx force:apex:tests:run --suitenames "your testSuite name" --targetusername "the username or alias for the org you want to run tests in"`)

Comment: I actually wanted to record the coverage report before it disappear.
1. I can simply fire TestSuite from Developer Console.
2. Create batch and schedule it's run after ~6 hours and record the coverage status in the custom object